# Glyphicons ficam sumindo no IE 10

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-glyphicons

Estou com o seguinte problema, estou usando os Glyphicons do bootstrap. Quando testo no chrome ou firefox, funcionam perfeitamente.
Mas no IE10 eles ficam desaparecendo, algumas vezes só aparecem passando o mouse por cima, mas ainda sim, desaparecem novamente, o que pode ser?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Visualizar" class="acoes-btn">
  <button ng-click="adiciona(tarefa)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-title="Visualizar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#visualizar">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
                              </button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insira e teste com a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

É válido lembrar que essa meta tag vem antes das outras tags, por exemplo:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx

---

Ou ainda tente ativar a opção download de fontes que fica no menu, em opções da internet, entre na aba "Segurança" e clique em Nível personalizado. Habilite a opção "download de fontes". Teste novamente.